# How do I create ad space after every nth post?

Tags: wordpress, post

I want to put ad code after every 4th post in my home page, how to do that (http://www.news.shreshthbharat.in/bharat)

Here is pastbin code http://pastebin.com/3vzhZKxE

I am using this code right now:

```
`<?php if ($count==3) { ?>
<div class="clear"> </div>
<--- ad code or widget area- - - > 
    <div class="clear"> </div>
<?php } ?>
<?php $count = $count + 0; ?>`
```

with this code, it displays ad after 2nd post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$count = 0;
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    $count++;
    $show_ad = $count % 4 == 0;
    //output the post
    //show the ad after the post
```

The `%` is the modulus operator. It returns the remainder of a/b. The loop would work like this...

EDITED TO CORRECT FAULTY MATH

```
$count = 1, 1 % 4 = 1, so $show_ad = false
$count = 2, 2 % 4 = 2, so $show_ad = false
$count = 3, 3 % 4 = 3, so $show_ad = false
$count = 4, 4 % 4 = 0, so $show_ad = true
etc...
```

Comment: Surely, you mean `1 % 4 = 1, 2 % 4 = 2, ..., 4 % 4 = 0`.

Comment: hi please have look my code http://pastebin.com/0u4Tg9Zd

this code working , can you define 

if i need to change as on every position ? what to do  

$count == 3 - [ show_ads - 1 ] 
$count == 7 - [ show_ads - 2 ] 
$count == 10 -[ show_ads - 3 ] 

i need different ad on each count, here is code i am using 

    `<?php if ( $count == 3 || $count == 7 || $count == 10 ) : ?>`

please have look this http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-adsence-code-after-every-post-in-home-page?replies=12

Comment: @Lstor.  Oy. Yes. Thanks. Will change. :-)